# Matrix multiplication results in fraction

Tags: ruby

Ruby yields results in fraction for matrix inverse operation but not for matrix multiplication operation. E.g., below code:

```
require 'matrix'

(Matrix[ [-1/2] ] * Matrix[ [1/2]])
```

yields `Matrix[[0]]` instead of `Matrix[[-1/4]]`. Why this behavior?

Comment: @Swoveland can you explain a little more?

Comment: I decided to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has been identified, but your real question has not been answered, namely, when multiplying matrix objects, when is an element of the product an integer, a rational number or a float?

If `a` and `b` are matrix objects, each element of `a*b` will be:

- an integer if all elements of `a` and `b` used in its calculation are integers;
- a rational number if, among the elements of `a` and `b` used in its calculation there is at least one rational number and the remainder are integers or rationals; and
- a float if at least one of the elements of `a` and `b` used in its calculation is a float.

I will give a few examples, but first let's consider how Ruby expresses rational numbers. A rational number is a number that can be expressed as the ratio of two integers. For example, `1.5` is a rational number since it can be expressed `3/2`. We can't write it that way in Ruby, however, since `3/2` will be replaced by `1`, the result of integer division. Instead, we create an instance of the class [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Rational.html):

```
r = Rational(3,2)
  #=> (3/2)
```

and use that in the calculations. (Note the parentheses in the return value.) We can extract its numerator and denominator, or convert it to an integer (rounding down or up) or a float:

```
r.numerator
  #=> 3
r.denominator
  #=> 2
r.to_i
  #=> 1
r.ceil
  #=> 2
r.to_f
  #=> 1.5
```

Now let's look at some examples.

```
require 'matrix'

Matrix[[Rational(-1,2)]] * Matrix[[Rational(1,2)]]
  #=> Matrix[[(-1/4)]] 
Matrix[[-1]] * Matrix[[Rational(1,2)]]
  # => Matrix[[(-1/2)]] 
Matrix[[-0.5]] * Matrix[[Rational(1,2)]]
  #=> Matrix[[-0.25]]
Matrix[[Rational(-1,2), Rational(1,2)]].transpose * Matrix[[Rational(1,2), 0.5]]
  #=> Matrix[[(-1/4), -0.25], [(1/4), 0.25]]
```

Now let's consider the inverse of a matrix:

```
Matrix[[Rational(-1,2), 1],[2, Rational(2,3)]].inverse
  #=> Matrix[[(-2/7), (3/7)], [(6/7), (3/14)]]
Matrix[[Rational(-1,2), 1.0],[2, Rational(2,3)]].inverse
  #=> Matrix[[-0.2857142857142857, 0.4285714285714286],
  #          [0.8571428571428571, 0.21428571428571427]]
```

In calculating the inverse of a matrix with `n` rows and columns there are `n` "pivoting" steps. If, as in my latter example, the matrix contains a mix of integers, rationals and floats, when each pivot operation is performed:

- each integer will be converted to a float if at least one float is used in its calculation, else it will be converted to a rational if at least one rational is used in its calculation; else it will remain an integer;
- each rational will be converted to a float if there is at least one float used in its calculation, else it will remain a rational; and
- each float will remain a float.

As "once a float always a float", it won't be long before all elements of the computed matrix are floats. (I believe it can be proven that the inverse will contain all floats if the original matrix contains at least one float.)

Comment: Thanks Sir Great!, for your descriptive and exact answer for the question asked. Particularly I was expecting your exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to choose correct type of data. Int divided by int is int.

```
1/2 -> 0
1.0/2 -> 0.5
1/2.0 -> 0.5
0.5 -> 0.5
1/2r -> (1/2)
(1/2r).to_f -> 0.5
Matrix[ [-1/2r] ] * Matrix[ [1/2r]]
```

so basically `Matrix[ [-1/2] ] * Matrix[ [1/2] ]` is the same as `Matrix[ [-1] ] * Matrix[ [0] ]`

Comment: Although **the result** of `Matrix[ [-1/2] ] * Matrix[ [1/2] ]` is the same as **the result** of `Matrix[ [0] ] * Matrix[ [0] ]`, they are not directly the same.

Comment: @sawa, sorry, `Matrix[ [-1/2] ] * Matrix[ [1/2] ] ` is the same as `Matrix[ [-1] ] * Matrix[ [0] ] `

Answer (score 1):

There is no fractional result for integer division. For example, 5 divided by 3 is 1 with remainder 2. In your code, `-1/2` is `-1`, and `1/2` is `0`. And `-1` times `0` is `0`.

Comment: If what's left is not sticky, I'd suggest "remainder" or "residual".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, "remainder" is more appropriate. I got confused with complex analysis (Cauchy's residue theorem). Thanks.